# Lucene subquery to return documents based on condition

Tags: search, lucene, subquery

I have two documents indexed like this:

```
VERSIONED_DOC
version=CURRENT
status=0
author=123

VERSIONED_DOC
version=ACTIVE
status=0
author=123
```

Both documents represent the same object in my system, with different versions.

When searching with lucene, I always need to get the ACTIVE document, but, if no ACTIVE document exists in the index, I need to get the CURRENT one. If both documents exist, only one must come (ACTIVE).

This is my query:

```
(version:ACTIVE AND status:0 AND author:123)
OR
(
 (version:CURRENT AND status:0 AND author:123) AND NOT (version:ACTIVE AND 
status:0 AND author:123)
)
```

The problem is that it always returns two documents when I have both ACTIVE and CURRENT documents. The second part of the subquery (AND NOT...) is not able to detect that I have ACTIVE documents.

AM I doing anything wrong? 
Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

To me a simple solution seems to be searching twice so Why don't you search two times? If you don't get any results in first search, search again otherwise stop right there & don't search again.

Four scenarios,

1. Only `version:ACTIVE` documents are there
2. Only `version:CURRENT` documents are there
3. Both `version:ACTIVE` & `version:CURRENT` documents are there
4. No documents with either `version:ACTIVE` OR `version:CURRENT` are there

So if you run a query only for `version:ACTIVE` then your scenario # 1 & #3 are covered & scenario # 4 is partially covered . Then If you get any results, stop there but if you don't get any results , try searching again only for `version:CURRENT`

Hope it helps !!